# How to count asynchronously all files in MongoDB GridFS bucket

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I need to count all objects in my GridFS bucket.

I wrote the following method but I guess if there is a better way:

```
public async Task<long> GetAllFilesCountAsync()
{
    var bucket = new GridFSBucket(newDatabase, new GridFSBucketOptions
    {
        BucketName = "fs",
        ChunkSizeBytes = 1048576, // 1MB
        WriteConcern = WriteConcern.WMajority,
        ReadPreference = ReadPreference.Secondary
    });


    var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Empty;
    var options = new GridFSFindOptions
    {
    };

    using (var cursor = await bucket.FindAsync(filter, options))
    {
        var fileInfo = await cursor.ToListAsync(); // <-- this returns the whole collection

        var count = fileInfo.Count();

        return count;
    }
}
```